# Development cost regarding android API support

Tags: java, android

Im relatively new to Android, and I am considering the possibility of developing an application supported by devices with API 1.6 and up, but I am unsure of what this will mean in actual code. I want to have some extra information that could be helpful in order for me to decide...

I understand there is supportv7 and supportv4 native API libraries, that aparently give support for older android versions (from 1.6 I believe) to more modern functionality.

But will this mean extensive code for the same functionality?

Will this mean having separate code snippets for same functionality for every API level?

Better yet, 
What major differences can I find between targeting, for instance, API 4.0 onwards by default or 1.6 onwards by default, if any?

Thanks for reading, hope I made myself clear.

Comment: Whatever data you are using now to make your decision will be entirely obsolete in 6 months. Just work with the most up to date API as of right now API level 19(4.4.2)

Comment: Less than 1% of downloads from the play store came from 2.2 and lower last month.  I wouldn't recommend targeting anything before 10 (2.3) and quite possibly 14 (4.0) if you were to release today.  In a release a few months from now I'd lean even more towards 14.

Comment: @CodeCamper Why is that? in 6 months nobody will be using API below 4.4.2? I dont understand your statement.

Comment: @GabeSechan I see. Maybe I start coding from 2.3 onwards? What I want to know however, is what would actually mean, in a rough guess, actual coding for the whole (or almost) of the API scope in comparison to targeting only the latest API.

Comment: @JustForFAULTS Just start programming in API level 19. Test your program on the device you are using. If you encounter a specific problem solve it. The answer isn't to use a lower API. You are asking whether you should make your program for Windows 95 or Windows 8. People show all these fancy charts of who is using what Android but they are forgetting these charts are moving so fast you are better off using the latest and greatest because by the time your done making your program stable and shiney it will be in the middle spectrum.

Comment: https://twitter.com/minSdkVersion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends. Typically speaking, you will need additional code to support older API levels, but it isn't different code for every level. The deciding factor to whether you need segments of code to support the API levels is whether or not you use the functionality that was introduced in the newer APIs. A quick example of this is the HOLO theme. This is a pretty common theme used to give android apps a similar feel, however it wasn't introduced until API level 11 (3.0 I believe). If you want to implement this theme and support pre3.0 devices, you need special code to handle that. If however you choose not to use this, there is no need for special code.

All that being said, some of the newer features are very convenient and make a programmer's job much easier. I think the last app I wrote I stuck with API 16+ as there were some tasks that would have been a nightmare to support pre API 16. I guess my thought would be to start coding with the minSDKVersion = 4 (android 1.6). The compiler will let you know if you have features that need special support for older versions. You will find out pretty quickly how much extra work supporting all the way back to 1.6 will take. Then you can properly evaluate whether you find it worth it to include the extra support or would rather adjust how far back you support.

Answer (score 4):

When deciding on API level to target this website gives really good information about the breakdown of the current market.

https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

As you can see API < 10 accounts for very little of the current breakdown.
I can tell you from experience that upgrading API levels is a pain. If I were creating a new app I would go no lower than API 14 as the minimum. Anything lower than that will be become further and further obsolete in a few months. You will not be losing too much business and will have access to a lot of the newer calls without having to use the support libraries.

Comment: Current market level is pointless unless you are planning on releasing the APP next week. Look at your data 6 months ago and compare it today. You are foolish to target a lower API just because of some chart frozen in time. Target the newest and by the time you mastered your APP it will not be the newest.

Comment: I was not asking this, but link is useful, thanks!